# ReactiveMongoDB plugin use id in JSONCollections

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.2, reactivemongo

I described model as `case class WorkAreaType(name: String)` and findAll method

```
object WorkAreaType {
  import system.db.Mongo.JsonFormats._
  def findAll = Await.result(Mongo.workAreaTypes.find(Json.obj()).cursor[WorkAreaType].collect[List](), 3 seconds)
}
```

JsonFormats:

```
object JsonFormats {
    implicit val workAreaTypeFormat = Json.format[WorkAreaType]
}
```

*Mongo.workAreaTypes* is a *JSONCollection* `val workAreaTypes: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("WorkAreaTypes")`

How can I read mongo _id object after call `WorkAreaType.findAll` in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick but not so great way is to define your case class as

case class WorkAreaType(_id:Option[BSONObjectID] , name: String)

The reason this is not so great is that this will make reactive mongo "leak" through your repository/dao/storage layer whatever you name it.

A "better" option would be to manipulate the json to "flatten"the object id before you read it to a scala object and inflate it after you write it back to json. This can be accomplished using Json transformers or JsZippers but takes a bit of research.